# Why NEC IR remote control decoder does not work

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

I need to recognize a signal from an IR remote, not to use a library for working with IR remotes/receivers. How can when the button is clicked to display its name. I have PIC12F615 microcontroller with this code: [code](https://github.com/circuitvalley/IR-Remote-Control/blob/master/NEC%20IR%20Transmitter%20Remote/main.c) and 5 buttons connected to him and I need recognise which button pressed. Why NEC IR remote control decoder does not work, it doesn't set nec_ok to true.If output nec_state to the terminal, I get 0 1 0 1 0 1 and so on.

```
    boolean nec_ok = 0;
byte i, nec_state = 0, command, inv_command;
unsigned int address;
unsigned long nec_code;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
// Timer1 module configuration
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
TCNT1 = 0; // Set Timer1 preload value to 0 (reset)
TIMSK1 = 1; // enable Timer1 overflow interrupt
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), remote_read, CHANGE); // Enable external interrupt (INT0)
}

void remote_read() {
unsigned int timer_value;
if(nec_state != 0){
timer_value = TCNT1; // Store Timer1 value
TCNT1 = 0; // Reset Timer1
}
switch(nec_state){
case 0 : // Start receiving IR data (we're at the beginning of 9ms pulse)
TCNT1 = 0; // Reset Timer1
TCCR1B = 2; // Enable Timer1 module with 1/8 prescaler ( 2 ticks every 1 us)
nec_state = 1; // Next state: end of 9ms pulse (start of 4.5ms space)
i = 0;
return;
case 1 : // End of 9ms pulse
if((timer_value > 19000) || (timer_value < 17000)){ // Invalid interval ==> stop decoding and reset
nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
}
else
nec_state = 2; // Next state: end of 4.5ms space (start of 562µs pulse)
return;
case 2 : // End of 4.5ms space
if((timer_value > 10000) || (timer_value < 8000)){
nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
}
else
nec_state = 3; // Next state: end of 562µs pulse (start of 562µs or 1687µs space)
return;
case 3 : // End of 562µs pulse
if((timer_value > 1400) || (timer_value < 800)){ // Invalid interval ==> stop decoding and reset
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
}
else
nec_state = 4; // Next state: end of 562µs or 1687µs space
return;
case 4 : // End of 562µs or 1687µs space
if((timer_value > 3600) || (timer_value < 800)){ // Time interval invalid ==> stop decoding
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
return;
}
if( timer_value > 2000) // If space width > 1ms (short space)
bitSet(nec_code, (31 - i)); // Write 1 to bit (31 - i)
else // If space width < 1ms (long space)
bitClear(nec_code, (31 - i)); // Write 0 to bit (31 - i)
i++;
if(i > 31){ // If all bits are received
nec_ok = 1; // Decoding process OK
detachInterrupt(0); // Disable external interrupt (INT0)
return;
}
nec_state = 3; // Next state: end of 562µs pulse (start of 562µs or 1687µs space)
}
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) { // Timer1 interrupt service routine (ISR)
nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(nec_ok);
if(nec_ok){ // If the mcu receives NEC message with successful
nec_ok = 0; // Reset decoding process
nec_state = 0;
TCCR1B = 0; // Disable Timer1 module
address = nec_code >> 16;
command = nec_code >> 8;
inv_command = nec_code;


attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), remote_read, CHANGE); // Enable external interrupt (INT0)
}
}
```

Schema: [image]

Comment: There are some coding issues to clear up before proceeding much further. Variables set in an ISR but used in the loop() should be volatile, e.g. nec_ok. Ensure also that compiler warnings are enabled in the IDE and clean up as required. There are probably other issues.

Comment: changed variables to volatile, if a warning is displayed: warning: 'timer_value' may be used uninitialized in this function, note: 'timer_value' was declared here
 unsigned int timer_value;

Comment: `unsigned int timer_value;`  make this static as so  `static unsigned int timer_value = 0;` . As static, it is initialised only once and holds its value between invocations of the calling routine (which is probably what you want here).

Comment: nothing changed, the same problem

Comment: I think that you have at least one basic problem that timer1 (16 bit) with a prescaler of /8 has a period of ~32ms. A typical NEC data stream is twice that. In the overflow vector of timer1 you reset everything. Anyway, instead of manipulating Timer1, you can simply use micros(). When you enter the routine, calculate the length of the last pulse and preserve the time (in microseconds) you entered the routine for the next entry. Something like `pulseLengthLastUs = micros() - enteredAtUs ; enteredAtUs = micros() ;`

Comment: To find out how far you are getting, create a global error variable, say `volatile uint32_t errFlag` Set it when there is a value out of range say `errFlag = 2000000 + timer_value` where the 2000000 represents case 2. Stop the program as soon as there is an error by doing something like this in the loop(): `if (errFlag > 0) { Serial.println(errFlag) ; while(true) ; }`

Comment: I changed to micros but still not working [code](https://pastecode.io/s/fm2ak7xc)

Comment: It looks much simpler but (a) remember volatile variables `volatile boolean nec_ok = 0;` (b) adjust the times for us and not the doubled timer ticks (c) add the suggested debug stuff so you know where it first fails.

Comment: If output nec_state to the terminal, I get 0 1 0 1 0 1 and so on,  if output pulseLengthUs to the terminal, I get 338020
380
176
200
180
196
176
200
176
200
180
196
180
964
1148
1056
1404
2680
2676
804
1164
1656
528
1552
39964
304
200
176
200
176
200
176
840
2800 for one click

Comment: you should have at least 67 time intervals ... read this https://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/NEC%2bInfrared%2bTransmission%2bProtocol ... or this https://www.digikey.ca/en/maker/blogs/2021/understanding-the-basics-of-infrared-communications ... and this https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/build-your-own-ir-remote-decoder-using-tsop-and-pic-microcontroller

Comment: If use timer I have this time values: 0
122
122
96
96
32
32
33
33
28
28
33
33
32
32
33
33
31
31
1827
1827
1736
1736
133
133
3422
3422
1072
1072
1072
112
112
95
95
32
32
29
29
150
150

Comment: you don't have enough time intervals ... the ones that you do have, are not in correct proportions

Comment: then what's wrong?

Comment: Please show your latest code. Maybe use the same link as before.

Comment: [code](https://pastecode.io/s/eyqjv1ri)

Comment: start by examining the remote control ... is it sending the correct code? ... also, please clean up your code ... it is a mess ... indent it properly and move comments away from the code ... comments are not part of the code

Comment: I used an oscilloscope [link](https://imgur.com/t7bStKQ), yellow pin 5, blue pin 2, and this solution works [solution](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/93087/how-can-when-the-button-is-clicked-to-display-its-name)

Comment: why are you posting this question again?

Comment: here is another question and code

Comment: looks like the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External interrupt version of NEC protocol decoder using micros() for timing instead of Timer 1.
Drops NEC repeat codes,
Otherwise, in the style of the code in the question.

```
volatile boolean nec_ok = 0;
byte command, inv_command;
volatile byte nec_state = 0 ;
unsigned int address;
volatile unsigned long nec_code;
volatile uint32_t errFlag = 0 ;
volatile uint32_t decodeStartAtMs = 0 ;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode( 2, INPUT_PULLUP ) ;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), remote_read, CHANGE); // Enable external interrupt (INT0)
}

void remote_read() {

  static byte i = 0 ;
  static bool wasSpace;
  static unsigned long enteredAtUs = 0 ;
  static unsigned long pulseLengthLastUs ;

  wasSpace = ! digitalRead( 2 ) ;
  pulseLengthLastUs = micros() - enteredAtUs; // Calculate pulse length
  enteredAtUs = micros(); // Store current time for next entry


  switch (nec_state) {

    case 0 : // Wait here until 9ms pulse found )
      if ( pulseLengthLastUs > 8000 && pulseLengthLastUs < 10000 ) {  // got a 9ms pulse
        decodeStartAtMs = millis() ;  // for timeout
        nec_state = 1 ;
        nec_code = 0 ;
        i = 0 ;
      }
      break;

    case 1 : // handle 4.5ms space
      /*
      if ((pulseLengthLastUs > 2000) && (pulseLengthLastUs < 2500)) {
          // silently drop repeat codes !!!
          nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
      }
      else 
      */
      if ((pulseLengthLastUs > 5500) || (pulseLengthLastUs < 3500)) {
        errFlag = 10000000 + pulseLengthLastUs ;
        nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
      }
      else
        nec_state = 2; // Next state: end of 562µs pulse (start of 562µs or 1687µs space)
      break;


    case 2 : // handle 562µs or 1687µs space
      if ((pulseLengthLastUs > 1900) || (pulseLengthLastUs < 400)) { // Time interval invalid ==> stop decoding
        errFlag = 20000000 + pulseLengthLastUs ;
        nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding process
        break;
      }

      if ( wasSpace ) {
        // we are interested only in the space length
        if ( pulseLengthLastUs > 1000) // If space width > 1ms (short space)
          bitSet(nec_code, (31 - i)); // Write 1 to bit (31 - i)
        else // If space width < 1ms (long space)
          bitClear(nec_code, (31 - i)); // Write 0 to bit (31 - i)
        i++;
        if (i > 31) { // If all bits are received
          i = 0 ;
          nec_ok = 1; // Decoding process OK
          detachInterrupt(0); // Disable external interrupt (INT0)
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}

void loop() {

  if ( errFlag > 0 ) {
    Serial.print( "Error: " ) ;
    Serial.println( errFlag ) ;
    errFlag = 0 ;
  }

  if ( nec_state > 0 && millis() - decodeStartAtMs > 90 ) {
    Serial.println( "Timeout" ) ;
    nec_state = 0 ;
  }


  if (nec_ok) {
    Serial.print( "Code received = " ) ;
    Serial.println( nec_code, HEX ) ;

    address = (nec_code >> 16) & 0xFF; // Extract address from received code
    inv_command = (nec_code >> 8) & 0xFF; // Extract inverted command from received code
    command = nec_code & 0xFF; // Extract command from received code
    if (command == ((~inv_command) & 0xFF)) { // Verify command validity
      Serial.print("Received valid NEC code: ");
      Serial.print(address, HEX); Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(command, HEX); Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.println(inv_command, HEX);
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Received invalid NEC code!");
    }
    nec_ok = 0; // Reset decoding process
    nec_state = 0; // Reset decoding state
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), remote_read, CHANGE); // Re-enable external interrupt (INT0)
  }

}
```

This utility can be used to verify the output of an IR receiver showing the timings of the pulses and spaces to  4us resolution.

```
// protocol analyser utility 
// intended to dump timings to the serial console for example from demodulated NEC IR codes
// Connect the IR receiver output to pin 2


const uint8_t DATA_SIZE = 100 ;

struct intervalRead_t {
  uint32_t durationUs ;
  bool space ;
} ;

intervalRead_t intervalRead[ DATA_SIZE ] ;

volatile unsigned long enteredAtUs = 0 ;
volatile uint8_t index = 0 ;
volatile bool firstPulse = true ;


void saveTimes() {

  bool wasSpace;
  uint32_t pulseLengthLastUs ;

  wasSpace = ! digitalRead( 2 ) ;
  pulseLengthLastUs = micros() - enteredAtUs; // Calculate pulse length
  enteredAtUs = micros(); // Store current time for next entry

  if ( firstPulse ) {
    firstPulse = false ;
    index = 0 ;
  }
  else {
    if ( index < DATA_SIZE  )  {
      intervalRead[ index ].durationUs = pulseLengthLastUs ;
      intervalRead[ index ].space = wasSpace ;
      index++ ;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode( 2, INPUT_PULLUP ) ;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), saveTimes, CHANGE); // Enable external interrupt (INT0)
}

void loop() {
  if ( !firstPulse && micros() - enteredAtUs > 500000UL  ) {
    for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < index ; i++ ) {
      Serial.print( i ) ;
      Serial.print( "\tinterval= " ) ;
      Serial.print( intervalRead[ i ].durationUs ) ;
      Serial.print( "us  \t") ;
      Serial.print( intervalRead[ i ].space ? "space" : "pulse" ) ;
      Serial.println( ) ;
    }
    Serial.println( ) ;
    firstPulse = true ;
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it does not output anything to the console

Comment: nec_state always zero and pulseLengthLastUs 238000
380
176
196
176
196
184
192
184
192
176
196
184
960
1072
1132
376
804
2292
2676
1552
2676
1500
1604
40988
304
196
176
196
176
196
176
836
2800

Comment: If using your [code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/93087/how-can-when-the-button-is-clicked-to-display-its-name?noredirect=1&lq=1), print from console when button pressed:  no code
no code
1C0
1DF
3
E
no code
1

Comment: How did you get those figures? You can't put a print() statement in function remote_read() because it is an ISR and will any way mess up the timings especially when printing so slowly at 9600 baud. The PIC software appears to generate an NEC repeat code if the button is held in. The code I supplied ignores these. Try only momentarily pressing the button when testing.

Comment: I only momentarily pressing the button when testing, but it doesn't print anything

Comment: i changed to your updated code but still not working

Comment: You've removed any print statements you added to the ISR? Did you see any message on the console at all? You can try temporarily changing the 31 here to say 30 or 29 just to see if there is a missing end pulse. `if (i > 31) { // If all bits are received`. If that does nothing, you'll have to work out how to use the proteus logic analyser. The oscilloscope resolution is too poor. I tested that code with an NEC remote control before posting it, but not the changes.

Comment: `pulseLengthLastUs` is always false in this condition: `pulseLengthLastUs > 8000 && pulseLengthLastUs < 10000` on any button press

Comment: There is then a mismatch between the code https://github.com/circuitvalley/IR-Remote-Control/blob/master/NEC%20IR%20Transmitter%20Remote/main.c (NEC) and its performance on a virtual PIC in that Proteus environment. That the 9ms NEC header could not be found is a strong indication of a timing problem. Use a logic analyser/(oscilloscope) to check the wave form and that the carrier is 38kHz. The carrier frequency is not critical but could be an indication that the PIC or environment is incorrectly configured. Maybe, just for testing, use an Arduino IR library.

Comment: The results don't look like proper NEC codes and the program will block the ISR for an extended period which may cause other things to go wrong. Whether that matters is another question. Anyway, I added an additional sketch to the end of the one that I provided in the answer. It will print out the timings of an IR data stream and could be used to see where the timing issues are.

Comment: displays the following when I press the button: [screen](https://pastecode.io/s/yo5qu9yz)

Comment: That is an ~8kHz signal with a 33% duty cycle. It is one quarter of the expected speed. It looks like the speed is too slow for that IR receiver component you are using to demodulate it and is passing it directly through, assuming you measured it at pin 2 of the Arduino. Anyway, without proper use of the tools in that simulator to check the timings, the exercise is like tapping in the dark.

Comment: but the frequency on the irlink component is 38kHz